# Is it possible to retrieve distinct attribute valued records of a custom entity in Dynamics Crm without using sql query?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2015, fetchxml, query-expressions

I want to apply distinct method on attribute values. I tried queryexpression, linq query and fetchxml but I could not find a solution 
for c#.

For example if I have following records

```
row1 -> A | E | A  
row2 -> B | D | A  
row3 -> C | C | B  
row4 -> D | B | C  
row5 -> E | A | D
row6 -> E | A | E
```

I only want to retrieve `row1, row3, row4, row5, row6` and not `row2`.

Comment: Seems to me row2 has distinct column values too.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? When you're doing a search in CRM you search for accounts for example, each account will only appear once in the list.

Comment: You are right, but I want to apply distinctness on column based, not row based.

Comment: This is called DistinctBy in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview), but with CRM you'd have to apply it to the data after fetching them in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Distinct command will only work on a per row basis.  If you truly wanted it to be a column level distinction, you have two options:

1. Perform two queries, one that selects on the columns you desire the distinction on and another to retrieve the rest of the columns based on the Id's of the first query
   -or-
2. Perform a single query, and use code on the client side to parse out the rows that contain the distinct values you're looking for.

Comment: Can anyone brief me how to do this?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I created a view with some filter, it has duplicate column values. how to apply distinct on that column alone?

Comment: Distinct only works on a grouping basis, so if you have a set of columns that you want to be distinct, everything else has to be grouped in order to have distinct values.